Why put your hands to your belt when kicking in WT taekwondo?
When doing practice kicks, I've always kept my guard up. Recently, my grandmaster has changed it, to bring the hands to the belt on the opposite side of the kick. When I asked why, he said that is the way the Kukkiwon says to do it now. Searching shows me only answers related to sparring.
I've been practicing for over 30 years. It seems awkward to bring the hands down, contrary to keeping your guard up, and I see no benefit to doing things this way.
Why is this Kukkiwon doctrine?
EDIT: Adding link to a video showing the technique. It is the Sip Jin form, and though the video is long (and informative!), you can see the hands position starting at about 2:23.

Could this be in order to prepare to defend a groin kick from an opponent?

I don't think so, since the hands are in a cup-and-saucer on the opposite side as the kicking leg. So the groin has no special protection.

It might help to see a video of the revised technique - it sounds sort of like a reaction force type movement - but where the hands travel for this will depend on the kick. I teach both maintaining a guard and reaction force with kicks depending on situation. Generally just bringing hands to hip/belt may "look tidy" and potentially help a little with balance (by keeping mass central and low) - but I have the same reservations as you with respect to practical guarding and power.

@Collett89 In trying to find a video example, I'm beginning to doubt my grandmaster is correct in the hand position, since tkdcon and other sites only show keeping the hands in a guard position. I'll have to ask him again; maybe he has changed his mind.

@MichaelFoster It is often useful to attend multiple sessions with senior figures - I have been to a seminar with a Grand Master where we spent hours practicing a movement in (to me) a fairly odd way - I attended another session with him a year later and uncovered that in the previous session he had noticed an issue with the way in which a few Masters did that move and was exaggerating the motion to "fix" it. The way in which I had been doing that move previously was fine..
If it doesn't make sense to you, or flat out doesn't work for your body - absolutely question it!

Probably the same one that you saw, but https://www.reddit.com/r/taekwondo/comments/y98frr/comment/it4x84o/ mentions "speed and power through improved balance" as the reason.

@Collett89 I just need to question it again. As I mentioned, I did question it, and the answer was that's the way the Kukkiwon says to do it. Confirming that is proving difficult, though.

The two reasons I could possibly think of would be balance and oppositional/reaction force.

@Collett89 I added a link to a video to the post (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOZB0IESJ38) where you can see this at 2:23.

There are two possible official sources for this change: Kukkiwon and World Taekwondo (WT).
Kukkiwon controls all things related to poomsae technique (in addition to a myriad things unrelated to your question).  And WT controls all things related to competition of poomsae technique.
If Kukkiwon says put hands on hips, then, WT judges will be required to observe and grade hands on the hips.  Additionally, there would be coaches supplementaries posted on WT's website acknowledging this.
I checked Kukkiwon's website's "Information" links, where traditionally, techniques are described in detail.  I additionally checked WT's website for coach resources.  And in neither place did I find anything related to changes, let alone anything indicating hands must be on hips.
So, let's look at poomsae.  Maybe there's something there that can help.
Poomsae in Taekwondo is a contentious thing: they're like the human appendix.  No one knows why we have one, and when things go wrong with it, Really Bad Things can happen to us.  As a result, it's best to remove the thing if we're in the neighborhood.
Taekwondo was bourne out of battlefield self-defense during the Korean War, then codified into sport later on.  (Don't fall for the Silla, Koguro, Pakjae dynasty spiel.  It's poetic, and nostalgic.  But it's a tale.)
Those who kept fast to the self-defense aspect split from those who explored the competitive aspect.  Poomsae had nothing to do, then or now, with sport sparring competition.  Nearly all techniques espoused in Poomsae (especially those in yudanja forms) are illegal in sparring competition; conversely, most sparring competition techniques are not present in poomsae.
And so since Kukkiwon has no self-defense curriculum, and its textbook does not describe in detail what the poomsae techniques are used for, poomsae is really an unnecessary thing.  We do it because it's required, but there is nearly nothing within taekwondo that describes the "bunhae", or applications, in the techniques.
It is clear that application is necessary to describe what to do in forms.  Do you chamber your hands in guard, or do you chamber them at the hips?  Well that depends on your interpretation of the technique.  If you can justify the intention of the technique, then, whichever way you are justifying is absolutely correct.
I will say that originally, hands were chambered at the hips (and not placed on the hips, as in hands akimbo).
There are those who saw that and claim, "That's insane, why would you not keep your guard up!"
Well, in sparring, you are not allowed to grab your opponent.  The chambering hands are representative of grabbing the opponent and kicking.  The detractors, then, are from the perspective of sport sparring - and they'd be correct.  The supporters of this are from the perspective of self-defense - and they'd be correct.
In other words, both are correct.
And you can compete either way in WT competitions.  And with no documentation requiring one way or the other, you'd be right.  The only caveat is that you must be consistent.  So in team competition, everyone does it one way or the other.  When performing a single poomsae, all kicks are done one way or the other.
Therefore, you get to choose.  (I should probably say, your instructor chooses for you :-)
Now, as to your instructor.  There is nothing I could find At Kukkiwon or WT requiring any changes to be made, or any statements made about placement of hands.  Most of the textbook photos and website illustrations indicate hands at guard, and as of my post today, they remain that way.
If you are going to compete at WT sanctioned events, it's best to keep your hands in guard, even though you only do that in sport sparring and poomsae has nothing to do with sport sparring.  I say that only because as I said all photos and illustrations have the competitors place hands in guard.
Now, I said all that without any deference to any specific technique.  There are some kicks in poomsae where hands must absolutely not be in guard.  Taeguek 7's knee requires to grab shoulders (or ears or head, whichever your instructor teaches) so that an upward knee to the face can be executed.  And there are several cases of side kicks where hands are place in a "cup and saucer" (also called dolzo makki, or hinge block - the hands form a kind of hinge; some say "little rock block" where you are holding a rock between fists... whatever, its the thing where both fists are at the hips).  In this case, you have no choice, there is no exception: hands at the hip, no ifs, ands, or buts.
Sources:
Kukkiwon
World Taekwondo
Note: The World Taekwondo site is legit, but, they do not have SSL on their website as of my post.  You'll get a browser error (with an invitation to continue anyway).  Some browser extensions will require only allowing you to go to sites with SSL.  In other words, the link with the prefix "https://" does not work, while the link with the prefix "http://" is required by the site, but may be disallowed by your browser.  It's 2024, someone over at WT needs to stay focused.
